# Codechef : Iron Magnet and Wall FEMA2

Tags: c

I have made this algorithm but it is still giving WA. I don't understand where am I going wrong. Please help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int calculatePower(int k, int j1, int i1, int s1) {
    return (k+1-abs(i1-j1)-s1);
}

int main(void) {

int t, i, j;
scanf("%d", &t);

long long int n, k, counter=0;
while(t--) {
    scanf("%lld %lld", &n, &k);
    char s[n], s1[n];
    scanf("%s", s);
    int counter = 0, countColon = 0, m_pos, i_pos;
    int length = strlen(s);
    int a[] = {0,0};
    
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        char ch = s[i];
        if(ch == 'M') {
            a[0] = 1;
            m_pos = i;
        }
        
        if(ch == 'I') {
            a[1] = 1;
            i_pos = i;
        }
        
        if(ch == 'X') {
            a[0] = 0;
            a[1] = 0;
        }
        
        if (ch == ':'){
            int sum = a[0] + a[1];
            if (sum == 1) {
                countColon++;
            }
        }
        
        if(a[0] == 1 && a[1] == 1) {
            if (calculatePower(k, m_pos, i_pos, countColon) > 0) {
                counter++;
                a[0] = 0;
                a[1] = 0;
            } 
        }
    }
    
    
    printf("%lld\n", counter);
    
}

return 0;
}
```

Here is a screen shot of the output.

[output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Pcg3.png)

Here is the question:

Chef loves to play with iron (Fe) and magnets (Ma). He took a row of N cells (numbered 1 through N) and placed some objects in some of these cells. You are given a string S with length N describing them; for each valid i, the i-th character of S is one of the following:

'I' if the i-th cell contains a piece of iron
'M' if the i-th cell contains a magnet
'_' if the i-th cell is empty
':' if the i-th cell contains a conducting sheet
'X' if the i-th cell is blocked
If there is a magnet in a cell i and iron in a cell j, the attraction power between these cells is Pi,j=K+1−|j−i|−Si,j, where Si,j is the number of cells containing sheets between cells i and j. This magnet can only attract this iron if Pi,j>0 and there are no blocked cells between the cells i and j.

Chef wants to choose some magnets (possibly none) and to each of these magnets, assign a piece of iron which this magnet should attract. Each piece of iron may only be attracted by at most one magnet and only if the attraction power between them is positive and there are no blocked cells between them. Find the maximum number of magnets Chef can choose.

Example input :

2
4 5
I::M
9 10
MIM_XII:M

output:

1
2

My code is executing correctly for these test cases.

Comment: Can you think yourself of more testcases? I.e. do you understand the logic of the challenge enough to judge yourself?

Comment: Did you try https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ especially the "rubber ducking"?

Comment: I founded out a case that I missed, which is why it was giving wrong answer

Comment: Great. Consider sharing your insight by making an answer. Otherwise please explain what you still need answered or delete the question please.